# Sum only when they have the same date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query in SQL Server where I have to show the sum of the records of a column that have the same date but for now it only adds all the records regardless of date.

How can I make it so that it only adds the repeated dates of the column and not all together?

```
SELECT
    FechaHoraReg, 
    (SELECT SUM(CantidaIngLamina) 
     FROM MovimientoMaterial Produccion 
     WHERE IdTipoMov = '1') AS FilminaI,
    (SELECT SUM(CantidaIngresa) 
     FROM MovimientoMaterial Produccion 
     WHERE IdTipoMov = '1') AS PapelI 
FROM
    MovimientoMaterial_Produccion 
GROUP BY
    FechaHoraReg
```

[image]

Comment: I high doubt you need subqueries. If you do need them then they must be correlated by the date column. Otherwise I think you're just trying to limit the sums based on `IdTipoMov`. Use this instead: `sum(case when IdTipoMov ='1' then CantidaIngLamina end) as Filminal` The other sum will be similar.

Comment: For learning purposes, the correlated form would be: `(select sum(CantidaIngLamina) from MovimientoMaterial_Produccion mmp2 where IdTipoMov = '1' and mmp2.FechaHoraReg = MovimientoMaterial_Produccion.FechaHoraReg) as Filminal` Don't do it this way though.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you a sum of the 2 columns independently

```
WITH CTE_FILMINAI
AS
(
SELECT
    FECHAHORAREG,
    SUM(CANTIDAINGLAMINA) AS FILMINAI
FROM MOVIMIENTOMATERIAL_PRODUCCION 
WHERE 1=1
    AND IDTIPOMOV = '1'
GROUP BY FECHAHORAREG
), CTE_PAPELI
AS
(
SELECT 
    FECHAHORAREG, 
    SUM(CANTIDAINGRESA) AS PAPELI 
FROM MOVIMIENTOMATERIAL_PRODUCCION 
WHERE 1=1
    AND IDTIPOMOV = '1'
GROUP BY FECHAHORAREG
)
SELECT
    MP.FECHAHORAREG,
    CF.FILMINAI,
    CP.PAPELI
FROM MOVIMIENTOMATERIAL_PRODUCCION MP
    LEFT JOIN CTE_FILMINAI CF ON CF.FECHAHORAREG = MP.FECHAHORAREG
    LEFT JOIN CTE_PAPELI CP ON CP.FECHAHORAREG = MP.FECHAHORAREG
```

This should allow you to independently find a sum of the two columns and change the where however you need it to be. Additionally, it is a left join on the main table in the event that somehow there is FECHAHORAREG in one of the CTEs. This also could be changed depending on what you are needed it for.

Comment: Hello what happens is that I need the subqueries because there will be other columns where the idtipomov will be equal to 2.

Comment: Ok let me update the query to resolve that then as well

Comment: If that is your personal opinion that is fine. However, depending on how large your data set is running a nested select statement could serious overhead (especially if used in large quantities). If you have feedback on the different way of approaching the problem you can simply state your opinion without appearing to be so heated about a alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs filter by id and the date, but the date is the same of the origin query.

Try it:

```
SELECT
    origin.FechaHoraReg, 
    (SELECT SUM(CantidaIngLamina) 
     FROM MovimientoMaterial_Produccion AS sub 
     WHERE sub.IdTipoMov = '1' 
       AND sub.FechaHoraReg = origin.FechaHoraReg) AS FilminaI,        
    (SELECT SUM(CantidaIngresa) 
     FROM MovimientoMaterial_Produccion AS subdos 
     WHERE subdos.IdTipoMov = '1'  
       AND subdos.FechaHoraReg = origin.FechaHoraReg) AS PapelI 
FROM
    MovimientoMaterial_Produccion AS origin 
GROUP BY 
    origin.FechaHoraReg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the values to ignore via a `case` expression. There's no reason to involve other joins or subqueries:

```
select FechaHoraReg,
    sum(case when IdTipoMov = '1' -- should this actually be a numeric comparison?
        then CantidaIngLamina else 0 end) as FilminaI,
    sum(case when IdTipoMov = '1' -- should this actually be a numeric comparison?
        then CantidaIngresa else 0 end) as PapelI
from MovimientoMaterial_Produccion
group by FechaHoraReg
```